# How to handle combined columns in excel with python's pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

So, I have an excel sheet that I need to extract some data and create a json with it, the issue here is that is a very large and kind of complex file, the first problem I encountered was that the sheet has some rows that are combined, and when I used the `to_json()` it returned the data combined as if were a single row. Here is an example of how the excel file is

```
---------------------------------------------------------
      Name    | property 1  | property 2  | property 3  |
---------------------------------------------------------
variableName1 |      X1     |      Y1     |     Z1      | 
---------------------------------------------------------
variableName2 |      X2     |      Y2     |     Z2      |   
--------------------------------------------------------- 
variableName3 |      X3     |      Y3     |     Z31     |
                                          ---------------
              |             |             |     Z32     |
---------------------------------------------------------
variableName4 |      X4     |      Y4     |     Z4      |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I get the excel with:

```
import pandas as pd
excel = pd.read_excel('testExcel.xlsx', 'Hoja1',  na_values=['NA'], skiprows=range(0, 1))
```

As you can see the 4th row has some combined cells (4,5).

To get the rows I do this

```
for i in excel.index:
    print(excel.loc[i].to_json())
```

And returns me this results:

```
{"Name":"VariableName1","Property1":"X1","Property2":"Y1","Property3":"Z1"}
{"Name":"VariableName2","Property1":"X2","Property2":"Y2","Property3":"Z2"}
{"Name":"VariableName3","Property1":"X3","Property2":"Y3","Property3":"Z31"}
{"Name":null,"Property1":null,"Property2":null,"Property3":"Z32"}
{"Name":"VariableName4","Property1":"X4","Property2":"Y4","Property3":"Z4"}
```

The problem I have is that instead of:

```
{"Name":"VariableName3","Property1":"X3","Property2":"Y3","Property3":"Z31"}
{"Name":null,"Property1":null,"Property2":null,"Property3":"Z32"}
```

I want something like this:

```
{"Name":"VariableName3","Property1":"X3","Property2":"Y3","Property3":["Z31", "Z32"]}
```

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
# Get the data
df = pd.read_excel('testExcel.xlsx',
                   sheet_name='Hoja1',
                   na_values='NA',
                   skiprows=2)

# Remove empty rows
df = df.dropna(axis='columns', how='all')

# Fill down the 'Name' values
df['Name'] = df['Name'].fillna(method='ffill')

# Define an aggregate function
def join_values(series):
    return ', '.join(pd.Series.dropna(series))

# Group and aggregate the data using the defined function
df = df.groupby(by='Name').aggregate(join_values)

# Reset multi index
df = df.reset_index()

# Serialize
json_output = df.to_json(orient='records')
```

Note that this solution will aggregate rows with duplicate 'Name' values into a single row.